# Rolling with slipping

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rigid-body-dynamics

What do we mean by the statement "Rolling with slipping"? I couldn't imagine this situation as a real life scenario.. I mean to say that if the body (say a solid sphere) is slipping , then how can it rotate at the same time ? If it will be rotating it won't be slipping . How can the two happen together?

Comment: Ever throw a bowling ball with some forward or backward spin? It takes a minute to for the linear movement of the ball to catch up with it's spin. same thing here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is when there is relative movement between a rotating object and the ground at the point of contact so the condition

translational velocity  $=$ radius of object $\times$ angular speed of object

is not  satisfied.

Push down too hard on the accelerator pedal and the drive wheels of your car will spin with the car and produce a lot of smoke due to the tyres getting very hot because there is relative movement between the tyres and the road - slipping.